# AS3 List issues

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, list, runtime-error

I'm trying to add a List object to the stage dynamically, but I always get an error when a certain line is called:

```
input.addItem({label:"test",data:"test"});
```

Error thrown at runtime:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
at fl.controls::BaseButton/fl.controls:BaseButton::drawBackground()
at fl.controls::LabelButton/fl.controls:LabelButton::draw()
at fl.core::UIComponent/drawNow()
at fl.controls::List/fl.controls:List::drawList()
at fl.controls::List/fl.controls:List::draw()
at fl.core::UIComponent/fl.core:UIComponent::callLaterDispatcher()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
at fl.controls::BaseButton/fl.controls:BaseButton::drawBackground()
at fl.controls::LabelButton/fl.controls:LabelButton::draw()
at fl.core::UIComponent/fl.core:UIComponent::callLaterDispatcher()
```

Anybody have any ideas how to fix this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Still broken...anybody have an idea?

Comment: is this the first item added to the list?

Comment: can you show little bit more code?

Comment: @Amarghosh Yes
@bhups That and the initialization code is all I have really.

Comment: do you have the List component and it's assets in the library ?

Comment: Yes, thats the first thing I tried.

Comment: Actually, I just solved this, its that stupid import to first frame error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe google helps ?

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=150778